# jQuery: how do I get the element underneath my cursor?

Tags: jquery

I'm making a drag and drop action, and I want an element to shift down when I bring an element over the one that is in my way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

a simple hack would be to say something like:

```
var hoverElem = null;
$('*').hover(function() {hoverElem = this});
```

then when you need to call what ever function to get the value, just use hoverElem

EDIT: this is a less resource intensive call:

```
$('*').live('mouseenter', function() { hoverEleme = this; });
```

EDIT 2: due to .live() being deprecated, you should use .on()

```
$("*").on("mouseenter", function() { hoverElem = this; });
```

Comment: Instead of attaching a mouse handler to every element (which also fires on `mouseleave` you should use `$('*').live('mouseenter', function() { hoverEleme = this; });`, it's a *lot* cheaper, especially the more elements you get.

Comment: duly noted. i figured hover only did mouseenter when there was just the first function in the call.

Comment: .live has been deprecated.

Comment: @moosefetcher - You down voted an answer from 5 years ago because a method was depreciated after that? Instead the proper thing would have been to comment (like you did) and then post a new answer.

Comment: Oops! I honestly wasn't aware that was a no-no, sorry.

Answer (score 8):

```
$('*').on('mouseenter', function() { hoverEleme = this; });
```

This is a lot cheaper then attaching a mouse handler to every element (which also fires on mouseleave), especially the more elements you get.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a standard way, but I would probably bind a "mouseover" event to all the elements you might want to move down if you are over them and then test to see if you are currently dragging an object.

Again, i don't really know your exact setup, but you could have a global variable `var currentlyDragging = false` then when you start dragging set it to `true`. Then when you mouse over an element you want to move out of your way you can test to see if your `currentyDragging` variable is true and if it is then you can move it.

Bit complicated, but I can't really think of any other way of doing it off the top of my head. :)